# "Necessarily" or "not necessarily"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, syntactic-analysis, negation

The idea that has to be communicated is that picking someone at random in the street, it does not follow that they are a tennis player : occasionally you mignt find such a person.

Is the following sentence a correct way of putting it?

- "People in the street" are not tennis players, necessarily. (1)

Is it not rather this next sentence that would express the idea properly?

- "People in the street" are not tennis players, *not* necessarily. (2)

If on the contrary "(1)" does  match the context, what can "(2)" be construed to say?

The first sentence is taken from an SE chat, and I need to make sure there is not something peculiar about it that I could have missed. The second is how I understand that the idea should be formulated.

([macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/not-necessarily)) **not necessarily** phrase

> not always, or not in every situation
>
> • Individual symptoms are not necessarily typical of the disease.

(Is there a difference relative to which variety of English one considers (BrE, AmE)?)

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to achieve with whatever the best answer to this question is.

Comment: Sounds like philosophy, not English. Like there's a theoretical meaning to "people in the street" and "tennis player". Both are noun phrases. That's it.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, I agree with that, I neglected this detail and copied the sentence as it was; in fact there is an error as the referent is truly people in the street, which fact has been mentionned in an answer. There is a slim possibility of scare quotes though, but I can't make out the reason.

Comment: Someone has to say it, a sentence "taken from an SE chat" is not necessarily a model of perfection. You should hear the sailor come out when I chat with friends.

Comment: @YosefBaskin We all have that problem to a greater or lesser extent ; nevertheless, those bad sentences on a chat are something on which to look into in those cases of incertitude as to what the error is or whether there is an error at all, even if, when the imperfection was ours, it can at times be  annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is correct that the second sentence expresses the idea accurately. On the most natural reading it means the same as 'People in the street are not necessarily tennis players', but with the stylistic twist that *not necessarily* is added as an afterthought, rather than included up front. (Incidentally, it is not clear why *people in the street* is in quotation marks.)

The first sentence means something else. On the most natural reading, *necessarily* in it will be taken to qualify the whole of it, so that its meaning is the same as 'Necessarily, people in the street are not tennis players'. That rules out the possibility that occasionally they **might** turn out to be tennis player after all, which is a possibility that the intended meaning, specified by the OP, leaves open.

Comment: That confirms the essential points I had in mind, and provides a qualitative analysis of the first sentence (your second paragraph) that seems to be accurate ; it shouldn't be contradicted by other answers. I'll just remove my acceptation if someone can convincingly show something different.

Answer (score 4):

I would say "People on the street are not necessarily tennis players."

The first sample sentence says essentially the same thing, but its separate placement of the words "not" and "necessarily" is a bit unusual.

The second sentence is somewhat confusing because of the repeated instances of the word "not".

Comment: I agree with your reformulation but that is not what I'm asking for.  You are saying then that '"People in the street" are not necessarily tennis players.' is the same as '"People in the street" are not tennis players, necessarily.' and that '"People in the street" are not tennis players, not necessarily.' does also (and is correct)?

Comment: I do not know *what* the second sentence is saying, because it is confusing.

Comment: Yes, _'People in the street' are not tennis players_ is incorrect and not rectified by a ', not necessarily'. If really required, a '– not necessarily' would be more usual to show a corrected statement (in quoted direct speech, say ... I'd expect printed matter just to show the correct version).

Comment: The second version only works if you think of "Not necessarily" as an afterthought. Suppose the speaker states that people you meet in the street are not tennis players, then thinks "Well, the occasional one might be", so they add "Not _necessarily_."

Comment: I have to agree that it's potentially ambiguous. Either "necessarily" or "not necessarily" can be used as a kind of tag or sentence adverbial (or afterthought, as mentioned) to indicate hedging, as well as being used as normal adverbs to modify some part of the sentence. So it's not terribly clear what is being modified (in particular whether "not" is covered by the scope). If you want to be unambiguous you should use neither sentence, and do what Daniel Asimov suggests. Sadly, a lot of questions here are "let me use bad English! Don't ask me to rewrite!"